# Submeter para mesma página e voltar para a mesma section

Tags: php, html, formulário, post

Amigos,

Tenho um site one-page em PHP que no final da página tem um formulário para contato que submete para a mesma página.

Queria que após submeter o formulário voltasse para a mesma section para mostrar a mensagem foi enviada.

Tentei fazer isso com o *redirect* com esse código abaixo, mas não deu certo pois quando redireciona ele não mostra a mensagem.

```
$redir = '#contact';
header("location:$redir");
```

Segue código de exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Site</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{margin: 0; padding: 0}
        #home, #work, #contact{
            height: 500px;
            border: solid 1px #000;
        }
        .resultado{
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="home">
        <p>Home Section</p>
    </section>
    <section id="work">
        <p>Work Section</p>
    </section>
    <section id="contact">
        <div class="resultado">
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['nome'])) {
                $nome = $_POST['nome'];
                echo '<p>Mensagem enviada!</p>';
                echo '<p>'.$nome.'</p>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="nome">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indicador no form `action="index.php#nomequalquer"`

e onde vc quer direcionar `<a name="nomequalquer"></a>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>My Site</title>
     <style type="text/css">
    *{margin: 0; padding: 0}
    #home, #work, #contact{
        height: 500px;
        border: solid 1px #000;
    }
    .resultado{
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
 <body>
<section id="home">
    <p>Home Section</p>
</section>
<section id="work">
    <p>Work Section</p>
</section>
<section id="contact">
    <div class="resultado">
     <a name="nomequalquer"></a>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['nome'])) {
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            echo '<p>Mensagem enviada!</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$nome.'</p>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <form action="index.php#nomequalquer" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nome">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    </section>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -4):

você precisa ancorar com um ID único. No caso sua postagem vem no banco.. então coloque um nome qq (não pode começar com números) + o id da postagem q vc quer retornar.

exem form action #post89

div id post89

Comment: action index.php#ancora e coloca ancora no form ou sua div