# Como verificar dados após submit de formulário e retornar resultado na div selecionada?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho dois pequenos problemas que tô batendo cabeça pra resolver, vamos ao primeiro:

1- Tenho o código abaixo logo após meu submit para verificar se os dados foram todos preenchidos:

```
    <?php
$data_coleta  = $_POST["data_coleta"];
$hora_coleta  = $_POST["hora_coleta"];
$unidade      = $_POST["unidade"];
$observacao   = $_POST["observacao"];
$solicitante  = $_POST["solicitante"];
$coletadora   = $_POST["coletadora"];
$erro         = 0;

// Verifica se os campos não estão em branco
if (empty($data_coleta))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Data da Coleta.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($hora_coleta))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Hora da Coleta.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($unidade))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Unidade.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($observacao))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Observação.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($solicitante))
  {echo "Favor inserir o Solicitante.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($coletadora))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Coletadora.<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se não houve erro
if($erro==0)
  {echo "<center>Todos os dados foram inseridos corretamente!</center>";
  include 'insere.php';
}
?>
```

O problema é que de cara o PHP está me retornando um erro dizendo que as variáveis não tem valor definido, isso porque ainda não foi dado submit no formulário para definir os valores(que é o que for inserido pelo usuário), imagino que eu precise então fazer um if para só fazer essa verificação dos valores após ser dado o submit, como fazer?

2- Acho que tem algo no JS do Bootstrap que tô usando que pede que sempre ao atualizar a página deve retornar ao topo, assim não consigo direcionar o action do form pra div que preciso, JS do botãozinho de ir pro topo abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1200);
        });
    });
</script>

     <a href="#" id="toTop" style="display: block;"><span id="toTopHover" style="opacity: 1;"></span></a>
```

Dicas?

Comment: Faz um `if isset` no seu `$_POST` antes de fazer a verificação

Comment: Tragam um Oscar pra este homem! Era muito simples, mas como tô aprendendo tudo sozinho desconheço algumas funções básicas e o que elas, fazem, muito obrigado! Só falta resolver a questão de retornar à DIV do Cadastro.

Comment: Faça um ultimo teste, na action do form coloca .php##support e em <a name="#support"></a>

Comment: A página não é encontrada, vou mandar abrir o resultado do cadastro(é um protocolo de atendimento) em uma popup, é o jeito, fica até mais bonito se eu conseguir configurar o Magnific Popup.

Comment: veja na resposta algumas considerações a respeito de âncoras.

Answer (score 1):

A primeira questão já foi resolvida pelo amigo leonardopessoa `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

A segunda questão também é muito fácil.

na action do seu form coloque o nome da pagina destino seguido de um #support

exemplo:

```
form action="index.php#support"
```

e na página destino coloque `<a name="support"></a>` no exato local que deseja ser direcionado.

[Mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201573/submeter-para-mesma-p%C3%A1gina-e-voltar-para-a-mesma-section/201576#201576)

> OBS:  `<a name="">` especifica o nome de uma âncora. **Não suportado em HTML5**

[FONTE 1](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp) ----- [FONT 2 -name attribute on img, form and a (use id instead)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-diff-20080610/#absent-attributes)

> Use o atributo id em um elemento para servir de âncora.
>   Exemplos: `<h1 id="support"></h1>` `<div id="support"></div>` `etc...`

Comment: Teve basicamente o mesmo resultado do meu código anterior, ele mostra que está na index.php?#support na barra de endereços mas não desce até a div de id="support". Outra coisa, devo manter meu script ou não serve?

Comment: Não é que vai descer até a div de id='suporte' e sim que vai descer no exato local que você colocar < a name="support" >< /a >, é um link que por não ter texto algum não vai aparecer na página porém vai servir de indicador. Evidentemente que deva ser colocado do lado da div='suport', que presumo seja esse o local desejado. O seu javascript não serviu nem serve. Joga fora no lixo, rs, :)

Comment: Mesmo resultado, mas analisando com mais calma agora, acho que ele tá dando reload e ficando na mesma div mas rapidamente após o submit ele joga para o topo da página, será que é algo no JS desse Bootstrap que tô usando? Ele tem um botãozinho que serve pra jogar pro topo da página, mas será que tem algo no JS dizendo pra jogar pro topo sempre que der reload?

Comment: Editei o post original com o JS.

Comment: mas onde está a parte do formulário?

Comment: <form method="post" action="index.php#support"> e o botão <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myfunction()" value="Cadastrar" >

Comment: e vc colocou na pagina destino < a name="support" >< /a > (sem espaços - copia lá da resposta) do lado da div que precisa

Comment: Pastebin da div inteira: https://pastebin.com/WbT3AH0t

Comment: testa aqui e veja se funciona  http://kithomepage.com/sos/fg.php é só clicar em cadastrar

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente, que zica, imagino que seja o JS do Bootstrap mesmo.

Comment: Segue a mesma coisa, como se nada tivesse sido mudado, eu tô pensando em mandar abrir o resultado do form em um Magnific Popup, mas já tô vendo que vai ser um pé no saco pelo motivo dos dados retornarem do SQL.